# how to delete a user from two tables with time stamp

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete users that have not been active on my db for the past 30 days. I have a table called userinfo and radpostauth. I am using this statement but nothing is happening.

```
DELETE FROM userinfo, radpostauth USING userinfo
LEFT JOIN radpostauth ON radpostauth.username = userinfo.username
WHERE authdate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));
```

it returns with no errors but nothing is deleted. Could any one please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well have you checked via a SELECT statement first, whether this type of JOIN returns any records …?

Comment: Did userinfo date format and the date which you got using date_sub function returns same date format ? like 2017-08-02 16:21:53 ( Y-m-d h:i:s)

Comment: NO  the select does not return any records i have this error when i do the select                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                           
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM userinfo, radpostauth USING userinfo LEFT JOIN radpostauth ON radpostauth.u' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

What about this -

```
DELETE FROM userinfo AS ui INNER JOIN radpostauth AS ra 
ON ui.userinfo = ra.userinfo
AND ra.username = ui.username
WHERE authdate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ui INNER JOIN radpostauth ra ON ui.userinfo = ra.userinfo AND ra.username = u' at line 1

Comment: I am new to DB pleas could you point me in the right direction am working with phpymadmin 5.1

Comment: What is there in this query to point to. Just use this updated query at the place of your query.